# How to copy screenshot into android clipboard (java/kotlin)?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, screenshot, clipboard

I make a screenshot of part of screen, convert it into `bitmap` and wonder how to put it into clipboard. Find the only `text` examples, so is it possible to put `bitmap` or something like that right into clipboard avoiding saving screenshot into file and using `URI` for `ClipData`?

Answer (score 0):

> Each Item instance can be one of three main classes of data: a simple CharSequence of text, a single Intent object, or a Uri. See Item for more details.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData

Official doc says, there are only three types you can use with `ClipData`. So, it seems, you cannot use `bitmap` directly, but you can save it and send its `URI` to `ClipManager` as `ClipData`.